# How can get User Session token from getstream.io?

Tags: c#, getstream-io

I want to add reactions to my Stream App. I saw this:

```
var userToken = client.createUserSessionToken(userId);
```

from stream documentation. I don't understand how to get this token. Do we have to make our own method for getting it or getstream.io has `createUserSessionToken()` method inbuilt. Can anybody confirm. Can I get one simple example how to get User Session Token.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The line of code you pasted is exactly what you need to create a session token; Please keep in mind at at the moment user sessions and reactions are only supported by the JS client

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a user session token on your server and send it to the client.

First `connect` to getstream on your server (use your apiSecret here, but not on the client):

```
const client = getstream.connect(apiKey, apiSecret, appId, streamConnectOptions);
const userSessionToken = client.createUserSessionToken(userId);
```

Return the token to your front-end.

On the front-end `connect` without using the apiSecret:

```
const client = getstream.connect(apiKey, null, appId, streamConnectOptions);
const userSession = client.createUserSession(userSessionToken);
```

Then to add your reaction run:

```
// activityId = the id of the activity you are reacting to 
userSession.reactions.add('like', activityId, additionalData);

// OR
userSession.react('like', activityId, additionalData)
```

Comment: How to get this userToken?